# Getting 403 Forbidden after changing webroot

Tags: apache, ubuntu, lamp, 403-forbidden, chmod

I am running Ubuntu with Apache (LAMP stack). When I changed the webroot from /var/www to /media/data/www, I keep getting 403 Forbidden even after `chmod-ing` the directory + files to 777. What did I do wrong? Also referencing /var/www, I noticed that the directory + files are owned by `root` should that be the case? Shouldn't it be `www-root`? Also if its root, will apache not be able to access it?

I noticed that I am getting errors like

> [Wed May 11 11:53:40 2011] [crit] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: /media/data/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable

but thing is, my web root is `/media/data/jm/www`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ouch, please avoid chmod 777, it's like having your door open with the key in the lock.

Error 13 is related to permission errors. In Linux, a folder needs a execute-bit to allow descending in it. So, make sure the permissions on `/media/data` and `/media/data/jm` is set to 755 OR 700 if the user running apache is the owner of the folders.

`root` is the god in Linux systems, you've presumably run the chmod command using `sudo` (`super-user do ...`). The apache process just needs to be able to read the files (and write if you're using a dynamic language which needs to write to a cache for example). In Ubuntu, this user is `www-data` (not `www-root`).

To restore the permissions and make Apache own the files, run:

```
 sudo chown -R www-data /media/data/jm/www
 sudo find /media/data/jm/www -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \;
 sudo find /media/data/jm/www -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;
```

The first command changes the ownership to `www-data`, the second changes file permissions to 600 (read-write for owner) and the third 700 for directories.

`/media/data` sounds like you've created a second partition. Make sure the filesystem support Linux file permissions. Ext2, ext3 and ext4 do. NTFS and FAT32 do not. You can check that by running `sudo file -s $(readlink -f /dev/disk/by-label/data)`.

Comment: I found that I also needed to set permissions on the parent folder, in this case `/media/data`